# How can I monitor docker volume usage?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, docker, docker-volume

I'm planning to automate docker activities using python. However, I couldn't find any efficient command for monitoring docker volume. So now I wish to use shell commands for that and later it can be converted using subprocess in python.

My requirement is when I give a volume name then I need the used space, free space, and total space of that volume for finding the storage threshold of the same.

I tried using the docker system df -v But it showing all details.

For example, I give the volume name as my_volume then I need storage details of the same only. Hope everyone understood my requirement and excepting a helping hand from someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I give the volume name as my_volume then I need storage details of the same only.

```
docker volume inspect 3459dffe0e309e11b3a09262dcd43ca3f54ee033ed01415a2bffad14faa8811d | jq -r .[].Mountpoint | xargs du -hs
```

Seems to properly output the size of `3459dffe0e309e11b3a09262dcd43ca3f54ee033ed01415a2bffad14faa8811d` volume.

Comment: May I know how to find the remaining space and total space from this

Comment: "Remaining space" "total space" - what is that? Remaining space of? You want `df` the mountpoint?

Comment: In order to check whether it crossed the threshold or not

Comment: so instead of `du` use `df`... `blabalbla | xargs df`

Comment: How I can implement this on python

Comment: `system(' ....... ')` If you are interested in python solution, you should tag `python` in your question.